# Angular/RxJS Observable piping from multiple functions

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, rxjs

So I have a http get function defined in a Service class that gets an object from an endpoint and does some processing on the result:

```html
public get(url: string, params: {}): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.get<IResult>(this.endpointRootUrl() + url, {
      params: params
    }).pipe(
      map(res => {
        if (res.Result !== 0)
          throw new Error(res.Message)
        else
          return res.Object;
      }),
      catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => throwError(err.statusText))
    )
  }
```

This function is called from an ExampleService which gets the observable and does some more processing on it:

```html
 public loadData(): Observable<IData[]> {
    return this.get("/DataLink/ListData", {}).pipe(
      map(res => { return <IData[]>res }),
      catchError((err: string) => throwError("There was an error retrieving data: " + err))
    )
  }
```

My questions are:

1. In the http get function where I check the Result property of the IResult object that gets returned from the back-end, I throw an error if the value of the result is not what is expected. 
   The issue is, the Message property does not get properly sent into the catchError part of the loadData function; the error message returns as "There was an error retrieving data: undefined". What am I doing wrong here?
2. Is this code an acceptable way to achieve what I'm trying to do? I'm open to suggestions/critique.

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move **catchError before all another pipes**, exept takeUntil

e.g.

Inside component:

```
return this.apiService.changeStatus(id, status)
  .pipe(
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      this.showMsg('error', error.error.message);
      return throwError(error);
    }),
    tap((data: SomeResponseModel) => {
      this.status = data;
    })
  );
```

Inside service

```
changeStatus(id: number, status: StatusesEnum): Observable<SomeModel> {
    const payload: { status: StatusesEnum} = { status };
    return this.http.patch<ResponseModel<SomeModel>>(this.apiUrl(`/${id}/status`), payload)
      .pipe(map((data: ResponseModel<SomeModel>) => new SomeModel(data.data)));
}
```

Comment: Tried to move catchError before map in the loadData function, no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

> In the http get function where I check the Result property of the
>   IResult object that gets returned from the back-end, I throw an error
>   if the value of the result is not what is expected. The issue is, the
>   Message property does not get properly sent into the catchError part
>   of the loadData function; the error message returns as "There was an
>   error retrieving data: undefined". What am I doing wrong here?

[Error object doesnt have `statusText` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

I think you are looking for [message property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/message)

```js
catchError((err: Error) => throwError(err.message))
```

With that change rest of code works fine.

**Example**

```js
onst data = {
  Message: "Random error",
  Result: 1,
  Object: {
    test: 1
  }
}

function get(data) {
  return rxjs.of(data).pipe(
    rxjs.operators.map(res => {
      if (res.Result !== 0) {
        throw new Error(res.Message)
      } else {
        return res.Object;
      }
    }),
    rxjs.operators.catchError((err) => {
      return rxjs.throwError(err.message)
    })
  )
}

function loadData(data) {
  return get(data).pipe(
    rxjs.operators.catchError(err => {
      return rxjs.throwError(`There was an error retrieving data: "${err}"`)
    })
  )
}

loadData(data).subscribe({
  next: (value) => {
    console.log(value)
  },
  error: (error) => {
    console.log('error ', error)
  },
  complete: () => {
    console.log('completed ')
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't think you understand; the issue isn't with the http error, it's with the 'throw new Error' line in the get function.

Comment: `catchError` operator catches every error. `HttpErrorResponse` extends base `Error` object so you can additionally get `statusText`. You can also change code to `catchError((err: any) => throwError(err.statusText || err.message))`